Get the most optimal combination of places from a list of places through graph algorithm
We are having a networking situation where he have four nodes - say A, B, C and D. The problem - A, B, C and D are not fixed, but have a bunch of possibilities.
Say A can have values A1, A2 upto An.
Same for B - B1, B2, Bn.
The same for C and D as well. Each of An, Bn, Cn and Dn has coordinates as properties (a tuple - (21.2134, -32.1189)).
What we are trying to achieve - find the best combination of An, Bn, Cn and Dn which are closest to each other if traversed in that order (A -> B -> C -> D). Example, it can be A11 -> B1 -> C9 -> D4 - basically choose one option from each of A, B, C and D from all their respective possible values so that the combination of these values are closest to each other among all such combinations.
We are trying brute force approach of course, but it is very expensive, since its time complexity is N(A) * N(A) * N(C) * N(D).
So we are looking for some graph based solution where we can harness a graph by storing all points with coordinates in it and at runtime we can simply pass in all sets of points (all n points for A, all k points for B, all j points for C and all l points for D) to it and it will output the right point for each of those classes (A, B, C and D) for which the route is most optimal.
If the graph needs to be stored in memory, that's fine as well, the quicker the runtime response time the better, memory is not a constraint, and also, whether a route exists between An and Bn is irrelevant here, all we want to do is find out coordinate based proximity (assuming a linear route between each set of points).
Also, it is not mandatory, in fact, it will be almost the case always, that the runtime query includes only few of the categories of places, like the exhaustive list has A, B, C and D, but a runtime query may try to find combination of just B and C, or A and D, or A, B and D, etc.

Wouldn't Djikstra's algorithm be relevant here? Of course, you'd have first to build the distances data, the complexity of this task being N(A) * N(B) + N(B) * N(C) + N(C) * N(D).

That is doable of course, since that would be offline, but how to do, or what kind of library to use to get it done and how - I need some help.

Hi @ravenspoint, yes, we want to choose one of the possibilities for each node that gives the shortest total path. And yes, I mean output one of the possible co-ordinates for each node, and optimal combination of alternative node co-ordinates - like A1, B2, C1 and D12.

@ravenspoint : though I generally agree with you, I think in this case the goal (minimal total path) was clear enough.

@Swifty you want to get accurate answers your questions needs to be crystal clear.  What on earth are we to understand from a question that asks for a "plausible" answer.  Sounds like the kind of answer you expect from an AI.

Yeah, I agree the issue should be clear enough in the title and not only in the description.

Hi @ravenspoint, thanks, editing the question. You can say that a bit nicely as well, no need to berate. :)

Much better.  You have been on this site for 12 years - astonishing that you haven't grown a thicker skin.

@ravenspoint agreed, I have a thin skin even though I have been violated by Stackoverflow many times! :)

Do you want the "absolute optimal" or just a "very good" solution? Perhaps you could employ a modern optimisation concept like Genetic Algorithm. Whatever. I think you should build and store the distance information (between successive sets) first.

Problem statement is that much clear that a networkx-based solution could almost be written. What are the A/B/C/D cardinalities ? Are these node locations static for 6 month or a year ? or doe they change every 5 ms, 15 seconds or 2 hours ? Are there any rules that would aid in putting a weight, heuristic or hard boundary on each edge ? Or a threshold value ? bouncing on @lastchance comment : Do you always need an optimal path (I assume it is distance-based ?) ? Or would it be better to have a population of good-enough path at hand ("good-enough" yet to be defined by you) ?

Oh God, that escalated quickly, haha. The answer to most of your questions is no, though, @LoneWanderer.

One option would be to build a KDTree for each category and query the alternating nearest place  :
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

kdtrees = {cat: KDTree(list(coords.values())) for cat, coords in places.items()}


def shortest_comb(places, categories, kdtrees):
    min_dis = float("inf")

    for init_name, init_coo in places[categories[0]].items():
        route, total_dis = [init_name], 0
        curr = init_coo

        for next_cat in categories[1:]: # from B and further..
            distance, index = kdtrees[next_cat].query(curr)
            following = list(places[next_cat].keys())[index]
            curr = places[next_cat][following]
            route.append(following)
            total_dis += distance

        if total_dis < min_dis:
            min_dis = total_dis
            mpr = route

    return mpr, min_dis


mpr, min_dis = shortest_comb(places, categories, kdtrees)

print(f"most plausible route: {'->'.join(mpr)}, distance={min_dis/1000:.2f}km")
# most plausible route: A6->B3->C3->D4, distance=43.50km


Used inputs:
import random

random.seed(1)


def rnd_points(n, cat, bbox=(21, -32, 22, -31), as_latlon=False):
    min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat = bbox
    points = [
        (
            random.uniform(min_lat, max_lat),
            random.uniform(min_lon, max_lon)
        ) for _ in range(n)
    ]
    if not as_latlon:
        from pyproj import Transformer
        transformer = Transformer.from_crs(4326, 32734)
        points = [pt for pt in transformer.itransform(points)]
    return {f"{cat}{i}": coo for i, coo in enumerate(points, 1)}


categories = "ABCD"
places = {cat: rnd_points(n, cat) for cat, n in zip(categories, (9, 7, 5, 6))}


Hi. Looks promising. So this KDTree should be kept in memory (or updated regularly when more places keep popping up) and queried at runtime with out list of places from query, right? What kind of runtime perf we are looking at, assuming hundreds of millions of places around the world, as well as memory footprint?

Hi, one more question, here the same ABCD is used as total data as well as input. That will rarely be the case, as our exhaustive dataset is hundreds of millions of places (all As, Bs, Cs... combined). The total number of places can ABCDEFGH..., but the optimal combination can be searched for simply B (B1, B2...Bn), D (D1, D2...Dn) and F (F1, F2...Fn).

Not sure I follow you. In any case, don't get too hung up on my example input. it's just to give you the general logic ;). I don't know exactly how you're prepping your data. Also, the code in the answer can definitely be optimized further but again, that depends on your data/workflow. And regarding your last point, that's something you never mentionned in your original post.

Hmm ok, but does your code depend upon all categories of places (A, B, C and D) be present in the runtime query as well?

Say you only have A and B categories. Then it will cost you N(A) * N(B) (at worst - a fancier data structure may well cut that) to find an optimal A for each B. Now add category C. In time N(B) * N(C), for each C you can try each B, and combine that with an optimal path to that B (already solved). Now for each C, you have an optimal A->B->C triple.
And so on. There are a number of (at worst) quadratic-time steps equal to one less than the number of categories. When working on stage (say) K, you need to remember N(K) optimal paths, one for each K: for that K, try each J, and then join that with the already-computed optimal path ending with that J.
It's a form of "dynamic programming".
CODE
Here's complete code, showing brute-force and the above; the suggestion is enormously faster:
EDIT: replaced quicker with a more memory-frugal rewrite:
from random import random, seed
from math import dist, inf

seed(12345678987654321)
def getnum():
    return round(random(), 3)

def getpoints(n):
    return [(getnum(), getnum())
            for i in range(n)]

NCAT = 5
NP = 30
categories = [getpoints(NP) for i in range(NCAT)]

def brute(categories):
    from itertools import product

    smallest = inf
    for t in product(*categories):
        tot = 0.0
        it = iter(t)
        last = next(it)
        for this in it:
            tot += dist(last, this)
            last = this
        if tot < smallest:
            smallest = tot
            best = t
    return smallest, best

def quicker(categories):
    old_dists = [0.0] * len(categories[0])
    old_paths = [[p] for p in categories[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(categories)):
        new_dists = []
        new_paths = []
        for new in categories[i]:
            smallest = inf
            for oldi, (old, old_dist) in enumerate(zip(categories[i-1],
                                                       old_dists)):
                test = dist(old, new) + old_dist
                if test < smallest:
                    smallest = test
                    best_old = oldi
            new_dists.append(smallest)
            new_paths.append(old_paths[best_old] + [new])
        old_dists = new_dists
        old_paths = new_paths
    winner = min(range(len(old_dists)), key=old_dists.__getitem__)
    return old_dists[winner], old_paths[winner]

from time import perf_counter as now
for f in brute, quicker:
    start = now()
    x = f(categories)
    finish = now()
    print(f.__name__, "ran in", finish - start)
    print("   ", x)

Note that I forced the random seed, so you should get the same output as I did (although, of course, the times may differ):
brute ran in 18.69626900000003
    (0.17976537535418252, ((0.339, 0.496), (0.333, 0.436),
        (0.333, 0.401), (0.318, 0.477), (0.318, 0.47)))
quicker ran in 0.0008059000028879382
    (0.17976537535418252, [(0.339, 0.496), (0.333, 0.436),
        (0.333, 0.401), (0.318, 0.477), (0.318, 0.47)])

Same result, but quicker is many orders of magnitude faster.
BACKTRACK
I advise against using a general "shortest path" graph algotithm. There's an enormous amount of structure in your graph that, as above, is highly exploitable. Another way to exploit it is to do a backtracking search over the whole product space, but cutting it off early whenever the distance so for is >= the best result seen so far. On my little test cases, it does surprisingly well. YMMV - very data-dependent.
def backtrack(categories):
    path = []
    best_path = []
    smallest = inf
    nc = len(categories)

    def inner(i, sofar):
        nonlocal smallest, best_path
        if i >= nc:
            smallest = sofar
            best_path = path[:]
            return
        if i:
            last = path[-1]
        path.append(None)
        for new in categories[i]:
            if i:
                test = sofar + dist(last, new)
            else:
                test = 0;0
            if test < smallest:
                path[-1] = new
                inner(i+1, test)
        path.pop()

    inner(0, 0.0)
    return smallest, best_path

Another twist is to use a different approach first to find a "pretty good" path, so that backtrack() can cut off futile searches earlier.
For example, store the categories is k-d trees. Pick some point P at random. Then build a path from the closest point to P in each of the categories (a k-d tree can return the closest in log time, and for this purpose it should suffice to use the tree's "settle for an approximation" faster search option).
With some luck, since all the path points are "close to" P, they'll also be close to each other. Lather, rinse, repeat, until you stop making "reasonable" progress. Then start backtrack() with the best you've seen so far.
REALISM
If you care to do a literature search, your problem is an instance of shortest-path on "directed, weighted, multistage" graphs. "Multistage" is the most important quality there.
Dynamic programming is a solution of choice, and I already gave complete code for that. It's spectacularly effective, reducing runtime from exponential to (basically) quadratic time.
But, in comments, you talked about having "hundreds of millions" of points. In which case, the problem changes from "challenging" to "no frickin' way - you'll never find anything that can solve problems so large both exactly and quickly". quicker() is just plain impractical if you have even a million points in some category (the square of that is a trillion).
You'll have to settle for approximations if you want results in reasonable time. Best I can tell, there is no useful literature about approximating shortest-path for multistage graphs.
If you want to pursue it, I gave some hints before. You'll have to do much more, though. If I were you, I'd run two processes. One runs backtrack(). Another (or more than one) systematically picks points P from a grid covering the XY space, and builds candidate paths from the closest (to P) points in each category. If they find a new best, they kill the backtrack() process and restart it with the new best. The process that generated a winning P may wish to start then on a new, smaller grid, centered on P (adopting a kind of hill-climbing heuristic).
backtrack() will probably never finish in such cases, before you run out of patience. At that point, best you can do is settle for the best it found so far. You won't know whether that's the best, or even whether "it's close". So it goes. Intractable is intractable :-)
Tricks like genetic programming, or simulated annealing, don't appear promising to me. Local minimums abound, and "deep" local minimums are separated by high hills. "Can't get there from here" via a plausible sequence of small local changes.
GREEDY
A plausible way to get a "pretty good" path is to use a greedy algorithm. Pick one from category A. Then pick whichever B is closest to that. Then pick whichever C is closest to the B picked. And so on.
That doesn't actually work very well, However, it can be made much better by rewriting quicker() to remember only the best LIM paths after each category is processed. So, e.g., when working on stage K, instead of looking at len(J) * len(K) possibilities, we look at at most LIM * len(K), and remember at most only the LIM best of those. This makes quicker() linear-time (rather than quadratic), but there's no guarantee then of optimality.
It seems to be a good way to find a good path with which to start backtrack(). Since it randomizes the LIM category A points it starts with, running it multiple times can yield different paths.
def quicker_lim(categories, LIM=100):
    from heapq import nsmallest
    from random import sample

    old_info = [(0.0, [p])
                for p in sample(categories[0],
                                min(len(categories[0]), LIM))]
    for i in range(1, len(categories)):
        new_info = []
        for new in categories[i]:
            smallest = inf
            for old_dist, p in old_info:
                test = dist(p[-1], new) + old_dist
                if test < smallest:
                    smallest = test
                    bestp = p
            new_info.append((smallest, bestp + [new]))
        old_info = nsmallest(LIM, new_info)
    return old_info[0]

GREEDY k-d
This is the most promising approximation scheme I've come up with. As before, proceed in stages, one category at a time, saving no more than the LIM best from each stage.
For the next stage, for each best-so-far path, try adding the FANOUT closest (to the end of the path) points in the current category. k-d trees make that fast and easy, provided the k-d tree has already been constructed. The code below constructs them on the fly, and spends the vast bulk of its time building the trees (for a category with n points, a roughly O(n log n) expense).
I'm using the very short pure-Python KDTree class (code not given here) from
https://github.com/Vectorized/Python-KD-Tree
It's a prototype just to test the idea. In production, if at all possible it would be better to construct the trees in advance, and re-use them.
def kdgreedy(categories, LIM=100, FANOUT=3):
    from heapq import nsmallest
    from random import sample
    old_info = [(0.0, [p])
                for p in sample(categories[0],
                                min(len(categories[0]), LIM))]
    for i in range(1, len(categories)):
        new_info = []
        print("cat", i, end=" ")
        kdcat = KDTree(categories[i], 2)
        print("built")
        for old_dist, path in old_info:
            p = path[-1]
            for q in kdcat.get_knn(p, FANOUT, False):
                new_info.append((old_dist + dist(p, q),
                                 path + [q]))
        old_info = nsmallest(LIM, new_info)
    return old_info[0]

The biggest "hole" is that it only tries at most LIM points from the first category. If an optimal path doesn't start with one of those, it won't be found. Running it again will try a different (although possibly overlapping) set of starting points. Again, this is intended to be used to find a decent path for backtrack() to start with.
AND GREEDY k-d BACKTRACKING
Idea: do backtracking, but at each level try no more than the LIM closest neighbors (via k-d trees). This doesn't guarantee optimality, but in every case I've tried so far does find an optimal path, and much faster than doing full backtracking.
kds holds the precomputed k-d trees on entry; kds[i] is KDTree(categories[i[, 2).
def backtrack_lim(categories, kds, LIM=5):
    best_path = None
    smallest = inf
    nc = len(kds)
    path = [None] * nc

    def inner(i, sofar):
        nonlocal smallest, best_path
        if i >= nc:
            smallest = sofar
            best_path = path[:]
            print("new smallest", smallest)
            return
        last = path[i-1]
        for new in kds[i].get_knn(last, LIM, False):
            test = sofar + dist(last, new)
            if test < smallest:
                path[i] = new
                inner(i+1, test)

    n = len(categories[0])
    for j, path[0] in enumerate(categories[0]):
        if not j & 0x1ff:
            print(f"{j:_} {j/n:.2%}", end="\r")
        inner(1, 0.0)
    print()
    return smallest, best_path

It can be used as-is, or, e.g., reworked to be a generator to find increasingly better paths for full-blown backtrack() to start with.
ASYMPTOTICS
It can help to keep these in mind:
In all cases brute() takes time proportional to
prod(map(len, categories))

Disastrous.
In all cases quicker() takes time proportional to
sum(len(a) * len(b) for a, b in zip(categories, categories[1:]))

Not only far faster, but also optimal in the worst case. It looks at each edge exactly once. To do better than that, an algorithm has to be able to deduce that some edges never need to be looked at. But in the worst cases, all edges do need to be looked at.
backtrack() is highly data-dependent. At worst it may take as long as brute(), although I'm not sure it's possible to construct such cases in general. As the number of points in categories increases, it's very likely to run faster than quicker(). At best, it can complete in time proportional to len(categories) + len(categories[0]) * len(categories[1]). For example, consider 100 categories that are pairwise disjoint, except that the first point in each category list is p. The first path it tries is [p] * len(categories), with total length 0. Then all other paths are cut off as soon as the first two points are picked. The algorithm could be changed to stop at once if it found a total length of 0, but that would almost certainly be counterproductive, burning cycles to check for something that will almost certainly never happen.
All the other methods given here do not guarantee optimality.
FOLLOW-UPS
First, after further testing, backtrack_lim() is the clear winner for getting excellent results relatively quickly. It remains effective even if LIM is cut from 5 to 2.
Second, a big surprise under PyPy 3.10.12: its math.dist is very much slower than CPython's, like a factor of 8 slower. PyPy is almost always significantly faster than CPython, but not in this case. That can be repaired in this case by using this instead:
def dist(x, y):
    return sqrt((t := x[0] - y[0]) * t + (t := x[1] - y[1]) * t)

although that's limited to 2D points and isn't robust against spurious overflow/underflow for very large/small floats. Note that ** 2 instead of multiplication t*t is slower - the all-purpose int.__pow() endures substantial overheads to get to the special (for it) "oh - only one multiplication is needed" case.

I coded a short example using networkx (which I learnt basics of for the purpose of this answer); the code is probably clumsy and could be shortened, but it should provide at least a base from which to write your code.
I made the graph based on this figure:

import networkx as nx
import math

nodes = {
    "A": [("A_1", (0, 2)), ("A_2", (0, 5)), ("A_3", (0, 8)), ],
    "B": [("B_1", (1, 1)), ("B_2", (1, 3)), ("B_3", (1, 5)), ("B_4", (1, 7)), ],
    "C": [("C_1", (2, 0)), ("C_2", (2, 5)), ("C_3", (2, 9)), ],
    "D": [("D_1", (3, 1)), ("D_2", (3, 5)), ("D_3", (3, 7)), ],
}

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(["in", "out"])


def add_edge(n1, n2):
    origin = G._node[n1]["coords"]
    extremity = G._node[n2]["coords"]
    G.add_edge(n1, n2, weight=math.sqrt((origin[0] - extremity[0])**2 + (origin[1] - extremity[1])**2))


for node in nodes["A"]:
    G.add_node(node[0], coords=node[1])
    G.add_edge("in", node[0], weight=0)

for node in nodes["B"]:
    G.add_node(node[0], coords=node[1])
    for a_node in nodes["A"]:
        add_edge(a_node[0], node[0])

for node in nodes["C"]:
    G.add_node(node[0], coords=node[1])
    for b_node in nodes["B"]:
        add_edge(b_node[0], node[0])

for node in nodes["D"]:
    G.add_node(node[0], coords=node[1])
    G.add_edge(node[0], "out", weight=0)
    for c_node in nodes["C"]:
        add_edge(c_node[0], node[0])

print(nx.shortest_path(G, "in", "out", weight="weight"))

Result:
['in', 'A_2', 'B_3', 'C_2', 'D_2', 'out']

Looks promising. Why adding edges though, since the actual route between them is not relevant here, simple cartesian distance can suffice?

As far as I know, Networkx's graph algorithms rely on edges, and needs to know that you can only go from A to B, from B to C... But as I said, I barely know Networkx, so there might be other more relevant ways.

got it. Thanks a lot anyway!
